# How to store data in a image viewing android app?

Tags: android, sqlite, pagination, android-application-class

I am trying to create an app that shows a list of picture(with pagination) from an API, and when you click on a photo, it opens the photo (probably in a new activity) with zooming and stuff. My question is how should I store the API responses? Should I

1. Store them in `Application` class
2. Make a singleton class and store it there
3. Use a SQLite database

I know the answer will heavily depends on the data, so at least what should I consider when choosing between these 3 options? Or are there better options?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

best answer is database

you can store image url and other info easily in a sqlite database

easy store / easy management

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the scope of your data according to your requirements.

1. If you want your data to stay accessible until app is running, then Singleton Class or Static Array (Create a static Array in some JAVA class let's say named "Helper" which is not being used anywhere, and access you array like "Helper.yourArray" to add or get data) will the best option.
2. But if you want the data to stay accessible until the app is installed in your device, in that case Sqlite database or Shared Preferences (Convert your JSON into String and store in Shared prefrences and when you need access that String, convert into JSON and parse to use) is the option you are looking for.

Hope it will help you to choose!